# Filter date by number of days with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an entity in my core data database with a field *startDate*, and a field *everyX* that stores how often the entity would be active (so if *everyX* is 2, it would be active every two days). I want to fetch all entities where the number of days between *startDate* and the current date is dividable by *everyX*. Figuring out if the number of days between *startDate* and today should be possible using a modulo with *everyX*, but I can't find a way to get the number of days.

For example these should be fetched:

```
startDate = 12.9.15
everyX = 2
today = 14.9.15

startDate = 10.9.15
everyX = 2
today = 14.9.15
```

These should not be fetched:

```
startDate = 9.9.15
everyX = 2
today = 14.9.15

startDate = 10.9.15
everyX = 3
today = 14.9.15
```

NSPredicate does support custom functions, but these do not work when fetching from a core data sqlite storage. So I would need another way to calculate the number of days between two dates that works when using a NSFetchRequest.

I know it would be possible to filter the entities using code after the fetch request, but I'd like to prevent that as I would loose a lot of the benefits of the NSFetchedResultsController I am using

Comment: `NSExpression` might be an option, though I haven't tried to do this kind of thing or checked the docs...

Comment: What is the data type for the `startDate` field in the data model, and of `today`? String?

Comment: `startDate` is date field. Same thing for `today`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fetch the data and use dates such as:

```
var formatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "DD"
var dayNumber1 = formatter.dateFromString(Your first Date)!
var dayNumber2 = formatter.dateFromString(Your second Date)!
var difference = dayNumber2 - dayNumber1
```

Or you should set your day numbers to another field in the CoreData and you can do operations with that field.

Comment: I'm currently doing something like this to display in the UI if a task is active on that day, but this doesn't work if I want to filter the entities during a fetch request. I somehow need to filter them using a NSPredicate for the fetch request.

Comment: I think you can not calculate the difference between days by using NSPredicate.